# Is faith in Christ something you have forever or do you have to work at it every day to keep it strong?

Tags: faith, works

What do the scriptures say about maintaining your faith in Christ? I know in Mormonism they teach that it's something you have to work at every day and slacking off can lead you to lose your faith and leave the church. But what does the bible say and what does Christianity say about keeping your faith strong? Is it something you have to constantly work at or is it something that once you get you don't lose?

For example, in Mormonism you might hear lessons about how you need to attend church, participate and read your scriptures or else you could lose your faith and fall away. Is that strictly a Mormon thing or does Christianity also teach that you have to work at your faith or else you could fall into Atheism?

Comment: Acts1:8 *But you will receive power when the Holy Spirit has come upon you, **and you will be my witnesses** in Jerusalem and in all Judea and Samaria, and to the end of the earth.”*

Comment: lol, being raised Mormon and thinking I was Christian made me think I could just ask a question. Turns out I don't even speak the same language ;) I'll look through those links @GratefulDisciple

Comment: Salvation is a fact just as gravity is a fact.  One must live as though salvation is true just as one must live as though gravity is true.  Believe in Jesus!

Comment: @Hardy As I commented previously, you need to scope your question because different groups answer differently.  [My answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89112/10672) is from the Reformed tradition, most common among evangelicals.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple thanks, it's fine if this is closed, I think your answer and that of Spirit Realm Investigator answered what I was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

From Protestant Reformed perspective, once you have a **genuine** saving faith (properly defined) you can never lose it.  Either you have it or you don't.  Our work doesn't contribute to it.  The growth has to do with our love response to Jesus (see long answer below).  Saving faith has to do with justification, not to be confused with other aspects of salvation: sanctification and perseverance.

### Long Answer

*faith* is a vast topic, and Biblical references to it are numerous, linking it to many related concepts and doctrines.  Not only that, *faith* is also central especially to Protestants, but leading to multiple opinions as well (example: Reformed vs. Wesleyan vs. Pentecostal).  This answer is necessarily brief and introductory, restricted to your key concern about **what part is constant, what part is changing, and what do we need to do to nurture the changing part**.

**I am answering from the Protestant Reformed perspective** as represented by John Piper and *GotQuestions* website writers.  Key positions in this answer are based on John Piper's three articles:

1. [Can I Have Assurance Without Joy](https://www.desiringgod.org/articles/can-i-have-assurance-without-joy)
2. [Love Is the Main Thing In Saving Faith](https://www.desiringgod.org/articles/love-is-the-main-thing-in-saving-faith)
3. [The Agonizing Problem of the Assurance of Salvation](https://www.desiringgod.org/articles/the-agonizing-problem-of-the-assurance-of-salvation)

##### First, some key distinctions

1. I will focus on [**saving faith**](https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/essay/doctrine-saving-faith/) which every believer has for *individual* salvation, as opposed to [**spiritual gift of faith**](https://www.gotquestions.org/gift-of-faith.html) which the Holy Spirit gives in various measures for *common good* along with other spiritual gifts.  **Both are gifts, and we don't work for them.**  But spiritual gift of faith is a matter of degrees while saving faith is either you have it or you don't (binary states).
2. Saving faith [has two aspects](https://www.gotquestions.org/definition-of-faith.html): intellectual assent and trust.  Holy Spirit, who gives us this faith, enables us to say YES to certain **facts** about Jesus Christ as Savior and Lord (intellectual assent), as well as to TRUST the **person** of Jesus Christ as Savior and Lord.  Many believers unfortunately only focus on **facts about Jesus** which the devil also know due to their spiritual nature.  Only believers **trust Jesus**.  Without trust, faith is not genuine.
3. Although saving faith [has important role in Christian life](https://www.gotquestions.org/Christian-life.html) (not just conversion), it is more prominently linked with *justification*, our imputed righteousness standing before God, which is **either a "you have it" or "you don't have it"** (binary states), not a matter of degrees.  But *sanctification* IS a matter of degrees, although in Reformed theology it is still NOT our "work", but based on the Holy Spirit transforming our soul.  Phil 2:12 about "working out salvation with fear and trembling" has to do with the sanctification stage (see *GotQuestion.org* article [What does it mean to work out salvation with fear and trembling](https://www.gotquestions.org/fear-and-trembling.html)).
4. Saving faith can be genuine ("warranted resting") or self delusion ("unwarranted resting") (see article #3).  It has to do with what we receive Jesus ***as***.  From article #2:

   > the question is this: Receive him as what? It is possible that you see Jesus wrongly and receive him as what you see, and thus receive a Jesus who does not exist. For example, you may receive a Jesus who is not the divine Son of God. Or you may receive a Jesus who did not do miracles. Or a Jesus who did not rise from the dead, but is only a spirit and influence in the world. Or you may receive a Jesus who teaches that your reception of him is not his gift to you but yours to him.

   Most people who are self deluded is because they do not receive Jesus as "supreme treasure" (Matt 13:44). Genuine saving faith receives Jesus as **personal Savior and Lord**. It is STILL about either "you have it" or "you don't have it", so it is not as though you can work your way from self delusion to genuine (I used to struggle about this a LOT when I was younger).  Warranted resting is based on "seeing the light of the gospel of the glory of Christ" which then enables us to rest on the **objective warrant**  of the finished work of Christ on the cross while we are being sanctified *subjectively*.  We either see it or we don't.  From article #3:

   > For faith to be real, there must be a supernatural “light” that God shines into the heart to show us that Christ is glorious and wonderful (2 Corinthians 4:6). This happens as a work of the Spirit of God through the preaching of the gospel.

   *GotQuestions* article [What are some of the signs of genuine saving faith](https://www.gotquestions.org/signs-saving-faith.html) can help us distinguish whether we are deluding ourselves or not, by self examination.
5. Once we have it, saving faith DOES have its up and down, strong and weak (Rom 4:19-20), little or great (Matt 6:30, Matt 15:28), and its growth (2 Thess 1:3).  **It is very important to understand that this is NOT talking about justification**.  We are either saved or not saved.  We are either united with Christ or we are not.  We are either adopted or we are not.  Even when we have a mustard seed faith it still means we are saved.  The variability as to do with **assurance** which goes up and down with stronger and weaker saving faith.  From article #1:

   > Scriptures tell us to pursue full assurance, they are calling us to fight for growing faith in God, *and* for growing affections for God. Because they are the same fight.
6. In the Reformed tradition, scriptures that talk about guarding the faith does NOT imply that we can lose it.  It is about the doctrine of **perseverance** which in the Reformed tradition the elect is guaranteed to be given sufficient grace to endure.  Guarding has to do with dealing with demonic attacks, trials, and temptations.  See *GotQuestions* article [How can I keep the faith?](https://www.gotquestions.org/keep-the-faith.html)  **In Reformed understanding, if a believer became an atheist later in their life, that means they never had a genuine saving faith to begin with.**

##### What do we need to do to nurture the changing part of saving faith?

I wrote the previous section to isolate the changing part of 'saving faith' so we don't confuse the changing part with other things such as the spiritual gift of faith (distinction #1), sanctification stage (distinction #3), perseverance (distinction #6), etc.  I also wrote the previous section so we are clear that saving faith is either "you have it" or "you don't have it" even though what we have maybe only a mustard seed (distinction #5).

So the remaining question becomes: **what is it that is variable in saving faith and what we can do about it**?

John Piper addresses this in article #2 linked above, based on a key understanding from Jonathan Edwards: ***Love is the main thing in saving faith***.  As pointed in distinction #2, genuine faith is trusting the **person** of Jesus, and trusting Jesus means loving Jesus as supreme treasure (distinction #4).  The key verse is Matt 10:37:

> I don’t think Jesus was teaching anything different from justification by faith when he said: “Whoever loves father or mother more than me is not worthy of me, and whoever loves son or daughter more than me is not worthy of me” (Matthew 10:37). And notice this *love* for Jesus that we must have is what you *feel* for your most precious family members.

John Piper distinguishes this love for Jesus (which is part of *saving* faith) from love for people (which is part of the *fruit* of faith):

> Be careful. I’m not saying love for *people* is part of what faith is. That’s a *fruit* of faith. Paul says, “The aim of our charge is love [for people] that *issues from* . . . a sincere faith” (1 Timothy 1:5). But, yes, I am saying that love *for Jesus* is part of what faith is.

Does loving Jesus contaminate saving faith and turn faith into a performance, or a deed, or a work?  John Piper address it this way:

> It is right to jealously guard saving faith as fundamentally *receiving*, not giving. To be sure, faith is powerful in producing the fruit of deeds, but *is not* those deeds. Confusing a good tree with its good fruit makes Jesus’s words meaningless. “Every healthy tree bears good fruit” (Matthew 7:17). So I want to be vigilant to guard faith as essentially *receiving*, not performing or giving.

What is this experience of loving Jesus that can grow?  As in all loving, there is **growth** involved in which John Piper terms "spiritual affections":

> think that for trust in Jesus to be authentic trust, it has to involve spiritual affections for Jesus. For example, I think that saving trust has to be *thankful* trust, and *admiring* trust, and *treasuring* trust, and *pleased* trust. In other words, if you say you have saving trust in Jesus, but you don’t experience Jesus as the most desirable, admirable, valuable, enjoyable person in your life, you should question whether you have true saving faith.

**CONCLUSION**: What we can do to grow our saving faith is to grow our spiritual affections to Jesus, grow our love for Jesus as being more aware of receiving Him as supreme treasure:

> This does not mean “*Do* things for him.” It means “*Feel* things for him.” Treasure him above all else. Be satisfied in all that God is for us in him.

Comment: `genuine faith is trusting the person of Jesus, and trusting Jesus means loving Jesus as supreme treasure` - sounds like you are conflating faith with love. What are your thoughts on 1 Corinthians 13:13 *"So now **faith**, hope, and **love** abide, these three; **but the greatest of these is love**"* ? To me, Paul is very clearly putting love above faith (and hope), not conflating them.

Comment: Also see 1 Corinthians 13:2 *"And if I have prophetic powers, and understand all mysteries and all knowledge, **and if I have all faith, so as to remove mountains, but have not love, I am nothing**."*

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator About conflating, please read John Piper articles #1 and #2 as he is extremely careful to distinguish faith and loving Jesus although both are tightly linked.  About 1 Cor 13:2, the context is Paul's rebuke to the church for bragging about spiritual gifts including prophecy and tongue but having no love **for people** since they are not using those spiritual gifts for community good.  Thus, the "faith" there is faith as spiritual gift, which is out of scope of this question.  This answer is about saving faith where the love is **for Jesus**, which is different.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator About 1 Cor 13:13, the context is comparing the spiritual gifts of faith, hope, and love with the other gifts (1 Cor 12:4-10) that the church was bragging about, meant for **community good** (1 Cor 12:7).  Paul was saying that there are lesser and greater gifts, and he ranked "faith, hope, and love" ("abiding gifts", 1 Cor 13:13a) above the others which will pass away.  1 Cor 13:13b says that among the 3 abiding gifts, love is greater.

Comment: GratefulDisciple, you just inspired me to ask this question: [Is love a spiritual gift or a spiritual fruit?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/73770/38524) If you know the answer, feel free to post!

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator The hard thing about studying the Bible is that the same word can mean different things although we can distinguish by contexts.  That's supposed to be the main meat of seminary training: proper exegesis that is the bedrock for building denominational theology.  I like John Piper because he is an expositional preacher (i.e. makes exegesis as the meat of his articles and sermons).  The quick answer to your question: Holy Spirit -> grace -> love as spiritual gift -> manifest in our life as love for others and improving character, which is called spiritual fruit.

Comment: Another question that you may find of interest: [Will faith and hope continue or cease when the perfect comes? 1 Corinthians 13](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/73771/38524)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133408/discussion-between-gratefuldisciple-and-spirit-realm-investigator).

Answer (score 1):

I think I can answer this question by quoting a [related question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/68422/38524) I asked on the Biblical Hermeneutics site, and the corresponding [accepted answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/68432/38524):

##### Question

> ##### Is faith a gift or earned through spiritual practices?
>
> On the one hand, 1 Corinthians 12:9 seems to claim that faith is a
> gift:
>
> > 4 **Now there are varieties of gifts, but the same Spirit**; 5 and there are varieties of service, but the same Lord; 6 and there are
> > varieties of activities, but it is the same God who empowers them all
> > in everyone. 7 To each is given the manifestation of the Spirit for
> > the common good. 8 For to one is given through the Spirit the
> > utterance of wisdom, and to another the utterance of knowledge
> > according to the same Spirit, 9 **to another faith by the same
> > Spirit**, to another gifts of healing by the one Spirit, 10 to another
> > the working of miracles, to another prophecy, to another the ability
> > to distinguish between spirits, to another various kinds of tongues,
> > to another the interpretation of tongues. 11 All these are empowered
> > by one and the same Spirit, who apportions to each one individually as
> > he wills. [1 Corinthians 12:4-11, ESV]
>
> But, on the other hand, other passages seem to indicate that faith can
> be cultivated / developed through spiritual practices such as prayer,
> fasting and hearing the word of Christ (i.e. reading the Bible (?)):
>
> > 20 He said to them, “**Because of your little faith**. For truly, I say to you, **if you have faith like a grain of mustard seed**, you
> > will say to this mountain, ‘Move from here to there,’ and it will
> > move, and nothing will be impossible for you.” 21 **But this kind
> > never comes out except by prayer and fasting** [Matthew 17:20-21, ESV]
>
> > 17 **So faith comes from hearing, and hearing through the word of Christ**. [Romans 10:17, ESV]
>
> **Question**: Is faith a gift or earned / developed through spiritual practices (e.g. prayer, fasting, reading the Bible)?
>
> ---
>
> Related: [Is Matthew 17:14-21 implying that miracle-working faith can be attained through prayer and fasting?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/68434/38524)

##### Accepted answer

> Faith is a gift, but the *strength* of one's faith comes through
> exercise.
>
> **Faith Is a Gift**
>
> > For I say, through the grace given unto me, to every man that is among
> > you, not to think of himself more highly than he ought to think; but
> > to think soberly, according as **God hath dealt to every man the measure
> > of faith.** (Romans 12:3, KJV)
>
> **Faith Has Proportions**
>
> > Having then gifts differing according to the grace that is given to
> > us, whether prophecy, let us prophesy **according to the proportion of
> > faith;** (Romans 12:6, KJV)
>
> **Faith Can Be Great *OR* Weak**
>
> > When Jesus heard it, he marvelled, and said to them that followed,
> > Verily I say unto you, I have not found so great faith, no, not in
> > Israel. (Matthew 8:10, KJV)
> >
> > And he saith unto them, Why are ye fearful, O ye of little faith? Then
> > he arose, and rebuked the winds and the sea; and there was a great
> > calm. (Matthew 8:26, KJV)
> >
> > Then Jesus answered and said unto her, O woman, great is thy faith: be
> > it unto thee even as thou wilt. And her daughter was made whole from
> > that very hour. (Matthew 15:28, KJV)
> >
> > And being not weak in faith, he considered not his own body now dead,
> > when he was about an hundred years old, neither yet the deadness of
> > Sarah's womb: (Romans 4:19, KJV)
> >
> > Him that is weak in the faith receive ye, but not to doubtful
> > disputations. (Romans 14:1, KJV)
>
> **Faith Can Be Tried**
>
> > Knowing this, that the trying of your faith worketh patience. (James
> > 1:3, KJV)
> >
> > That the trial of your faith, being much more precious than of gold
> > that perisheth, though it be tried with fire, might be found unto
> > praise and honour and glory at the appearing of Jesus Christ: (1 Peter
> > 1:7, KJV)
>
> Once our faith is tried and purified, as alluded to in these passages,
> it becomes stronger/greater.
>
> > But ye, beloved, building up yourselves on **your most holy faith,**
> > praying in the Holy Ghost, (Jude 1:20, KJV)
>
> **Summary**
>
> Everyone starts with a God-given measure of faith.  God desires us to
> exercise that faith through the trials or tests of faith through which
> we pass until our faith becomes great.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to faith as the ongoing trust in God's promises that leads to participating in God's plans and works, rather than the faith in Christ that leads to Salvation.

I like to describe faith as a spiritual muscle.  Just like any muscle, it can be strengthened by exercise.  In James 1, we learn that trials test our faith, increasing our stamina.  This is the spiritual exercise routine, and prepares us for greater trials, which in turn increase our faith when navigated successfully.  Prayer, scripture and fellowship are additional parts of the spiritual exercise as they all improve our stamina.  This stamina enables us to endure ever greater trials.  God can also grant superhuman faith directly to us, similar to granting Samson superhuman muscular strength.

If you are referring to the faith leading to salvation, I believe salvation is permanent, cannot be lost and is not in any way related to the works we perform.  Salvation is a gift, which He bought with His blood to pay for our sins.  We are adopted into His family.  Our sins are washed away.  These descriptions used in the Bible imply permanency.  An adopted child cannot be disinherited.  A blood sacrifice cannot be refunded or reversed.  A stain removed cannot be restored. (I also believe Jesus blood covers the sins we have not yet committed.  When I sin after salvation, I damage my relationship with God, but my soul is still secure.)  Our responsibility is to accept His gift.  We should not boast about the work we perform, but we can boast in Christ's work on the cross (Gal 6:14), because we did not EARN it, we ACCEPTED it.